# How do I further improve read/step performance for SQLite lookup tables?

Tags: c++, performance, sqlite, cross-platform

**The Setup:**

For a C++ cross-platform project, I have several read-only look-up tables in SQLite. The one I'm concerned with at the moment (profiling indicates it takes ~72% of the algorithm's complete time) is rather simple. Given a table with four columns, all of them 64-bit integers, find the (unique) entry in column four given the first three. In other words:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE A=?1 AND B=?2 AND C=?3;
```

The actual look-ups are being done in chunks, where A and B are fixed and C is retrieved from a vector. I've also got a covering index (think that's what it's called): my index is on A,B,C, and D, even though I only use A, B, and C to do the lookups. Or:

```
CREATE INDEX covered_index ON table_name(A, B, C, D);
```

My code calls every combination of A and B (chunking). The sub-code takes a vector that has a class with C in it; then I do a calculation for every entry in the vector based on it's D, which is looked up based on the passed in A, B and the vector entry's C. In other words:

```
class Foo
{
   int64_t someC;
   ...
};

...

// This will be called once for every combination of A, B
void Bar(const std::vector<class Foo> &fooVector, int64_t fixedA, int64_t fixedB)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < fooVector.size(); i++)
    {
        int64_t d = GetD(fixedA, fixedB, fooVector[i].someC);
        (do a calculation based on D)
    }
}

// Reuse the prepared select statement: SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE A=?1 AND B=?2 AND C=?3;
int64_t GetD(int64_t a, int64_t b, int64_t c)
{
    reset();
    bind(a, 1);
    bind(b, 2);
    bind(c, 3);
    if(step() == SQLITE_ROW)
    {
        return getInt64FromColumn(4);
    }
    // Throw an error if the select fails ...
}
```

This calling method is combinatorial ( O(N!) IIRC), so even a tiny improvement can make a huge difference. The data sets are expected to get somewhat large; for tiny data sets what I've got right now is sufficient. The code needs to work for both Linux & Windows, and it's expected to be ported to Android (where memory is at a premium).

I'm using a covering index where A and B are first, so I don't expect data localization to be a problem. Compression -- `VACUUM` -- if I'm reading the docs right, won't do anything for me since my tables have no deleted entries. I downloaded the latest SQLite last night, and that doesn't seem to make a difference. I'm also using a "cutoff" to not bother doing the read and calculation outside of certain boundaries (which gives a 5-600% improvement by itself). I also tried reading all of the D values for a given A, B as in:

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE A=?1 AND B=?2;
```

and storing the results in a map (`std::map<int64_t, int64_t>` for C, D; a sort of primitive cache)  but this approach actually (significantly) *worsened* performance -- the combination of map inserts and steps doubled or tripled the amount of time required.

So far I *haven't* used `ANALYZE` or defined the database as "read only" in the DB open. I'm willing to try that, but unsure as to what to expect as far as performance goes. My colleague suggested further chunking the reads, but I'm not sure how to accomplish that at this point.

The time for the `reset()`, `bind()`, and `getInt64FromColumn(4)` methods is trivial -- they are simple wrappers on the SQLite C API and take negligible amounts of time.

**The Question:**

Is there anything I'm missing here to improve read performance? I only need to worry about read performance; the databases themselves will be generated elsewhere and are not expected to change. (More precisely, when they do change, the DB will be generated elsewhere and installed via file copy).

Comment: There is a lot of code missing, the preparation of the statement, where is executed, where is declared, the code of the method `reset`, `bind`, `step`. The more obvious optimization is reusing as much as possible of the prepared statement, the second try would be, fix the value of `a` and `b` in every chuck of `c`

Comment: Run [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) on this query to check that the covering index is used. However, everything looks OK; what is the actual runtime of `GetD`? What are the actual ranges of A/B/C?

Comment: Yep. Ran the EXPLAIN and it's searching the table using a Covering Index. The test data I'm using is random, so the ranges of A, B, and C pretty large ... max of 87654321 or something absurd like that.